# C# Winforms Cross Thread event extremely slow posting to HTTPClient

Tags: multithreading, winforms

The following code is a serial port event inside a winforms form ( so obviously running on it's own thread ). The slow line of code is run elsewhere ( in Nodejs ) and takes about 10 seconds. In this code the same line takes 45 seconds - sometimes 60 seconds.

```
private async void SerialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
    string indata = sp.ReadLine().Replace("?","").Replace(" ","");
    if(indata != null)
    {
        var weightMatch = Regex.Match(indata, @"(\d+\.\d+)kg$");
        var weight = weightMatch.Groups[1].Value;
        var message = barcode + "  Weight:" + weight;
        this.Invoke(new Action(() => { scanData.Add(new ScanDataItem(scanData.Count + 1, message, "")); }));
        this.Invoke(new Action(() => { mainList.SelectedIndex = mainList.Items.Count - 1; }));
        string jsonData = "";
        // ***************************************************************
        // The following line is about 30 seconds slower than it should be - inner function calls a web service
        // ***************************************************************
        var jsonString = await TrayWeighScan.doOrder(barcode, Decimal.Parse(weight));

        try
        {
            var jsonDoc = JsonDocument.Parse(jsonString);
            jsonData = JsonSerializer.Serialize(jsonDoc, new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true });
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            jsonData = jsonString;
        }
        this.Invoke(new Action(() => { scanData.Last().responseData = jsonData; }));
        this.Invoke(new Action(() => { responseTextBox.Text = jsonData; }));
        this.Invoke(new Action(() => { statusTextBox.Text = "Ready to Scan"; }));
        this.Invoke(new Action(() => { busy = false; }));

    }
}

public class TrayWeighScan
{
    //private static readonly HttpClient httpClient = new();

    public static async Task<string> doOrder(string orderNumber, decimal weight ) 
    {
        HttpClient httpClient = new();
        var url = "http://r2hserver/logistics/weighscan?orderNumber="+orderNumber+"&weight="+weight.ToString("F2");
        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
        string responseText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return responseText;
    }
}
```

If I run the "slow" line directly from a form button, 11 seconds.

```
private async void btnUrlTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string orderNumber = "ORD100302338";
    decimal weight = 1.606m;
    //following line - 11 seconds.
    var a = await TrayWeighScan.doOrder(orderNumber,weight);
    var b = "";
 }
```

Comment: It says async. How did you turn this into async from the secondary thread?

Comment: What are you asking us?

Comment: Your code has a bunch of `this.Invoke` - at most it should have one. You're also saying that the `trayWeighScan.doOrder` is the slow line, yet you haven't shown us the source for this code. You really need to refactor your code as a whole, but until we see the whole it's hard to give suggestions. We need a [mcve].

Comment: It's not performant code, but delays *that* long have only two good reasons.  Could be anti-malware, could be network timeouts.  Conveniently the default HTTP connection timeout is 45 seconds so provides an easy explanation.

Comment: Enigmativity - it's only that single line that is slow, and all it is doing is calling a web service with HttpClient that takes about 8-10 seconds.  but that line takes 45-60 seconds

Comment: @MartinThompson - That single line of code is made up of many lines of code. It would be helpful to see that code to know what's going on. Please always show all of the code.

Comment: I have added the class that contains the execution of HTTClient GET to web service.  If I do the GET directly through nodejs it is much faster.

Comment: Is the value of `barcode` the same as `"ORD100302338"` in your `btnUrlTest_Click` handler? How do you know that the execution time is 11 seconds? How are you timing that?

Comment: yes - barcode is exactly the same.  This line of code takes different amounts of time depending on where it's called from :  HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url) . I breakpoiint just before it.

Comment: @MartinThompson - You're not answering all of my questions. You answered the first, but ignored the next two. How do you know it took 11 seconds? How are you timing it? The code you posted is incomplete and doesn't show how you worked out the timing. You need to provide the full code - a [mcve].

Comment: This: `HttpClient httpClient = new();` in `TrayWeighScan.doOrder()` is a tragedy. This is not the way HttpClient works (it's also not disposed) and called from a `DataReceived` handler adds to the tragedy. You need to declare a static HttpClient object that is disposed when the operations are terminated (or, as in your case, when the Form closes) + You cannot have synch code in the event handler; `Invoke()`, instead of `BeginInvoke()`, makes those calls synchronous. When some complete data is received, you should (ought to) enqueue a Task that does the processing, leaving the handler free.

Comment: OK - I have to go but I will get more detail later ( and thanks so much for sticking with this ) .  I re-created the form - even re-created the web service with a mock delay in it.  The form I created works fine - but my code is delayed.

Comment: What I think is happening is that there is another event that is using COM Interop and this whole process is started by a barcode scan ( zebra ) that uses this interop.  The barcode event writes to the scales ( standard serial port )  - and the serial port independently writes the weight back to another event.  If I leave the scanner part out - everything works fine - but of course I need the scanner.

Comment: As mentioned, the first thing you have to do is to remove `HttpClient httpClient = new();`, declare a static object in your `TrayWeighScan` class. For example: `private static Lazy<HttpClient> client = new Lazy<HttpClient>(()=> {  var handler = new HttpClientHandler(); var hc = new HttpClient(handler) {Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10) }; return hc; });` -- Configure the HttpClientHandler, if required, add some headers, if necessary and set the `TimeOut` to a *sensible* value. -- The code that handles the data arrival must run outside the `DataReceived` Thread context.

Comment: The UI updates should be performed using an `IProgress<T>` delegate, created in the UI Thread and passed to the class that handles the data processing, which only calls the `Report()` method to set the new data. No `Invoke()` stuff. The class should implement `IDisposable`, where the `Dispose()` method disposes of the HttpClient object.

Comment: Thanks Jimi - you mean like a backgroundworker class?

Comment: Also I notice Devexpress seem to use the Invoke stuff to update the UI ..?  https://github.com/DevExpress-Examples/winforms-update-grid-datasource-from-separate-thread/blob/13.1.4%2B/CS/Thread/Form1.cs

Comment: No `Invoke()` mean, literally, don't use the `Invoke()` method. `Invoke()` != `BeginInvoke()` (as you see in the example you have linked).  `Invoke()` is synchronous, in a GUI as WinForms a deadlock is that improbable. `BeginInvoke()` is asynchronous, it enqueues a messages in the MessageQueue and returns immediately. The same thing you should do. In the example, when the timer Tick (associate it to your `DataReceived` event), the work is sent to a Task. Consider, though, that a Timer ticks predictably, while `DataReceived` is raised without specific timing, so you usually enqueue the work...

Comment: ... in a concurrent collection (`ConcurrentQueue`, `ConcurrentBag` etc.) and a dedicated Theard or long running Task dequeues the work item, processes it, updates the UI then dequeues the next work item, if any is present.  So the `DataReceived` just offloads immediately any work related to any data received: no work is done in the handler (you cannot block it in any way). -- To update the UI, you *could* `BeginInvoke()`, but a dedicated `IProgress<T>` delegate is much better in this scenario (much better).

Comment: OK - you've completely lost me.  I have removed all the references invoking anything on the main thread so I can isolate the issues with the class running over time.  I put a time limit on the code you wrote - and yet is times out if I run it in another thread - but not if I run it straight from a button.

Comment: This stuff is a piece of cake in nodejs - why is it so damn complicated here?   I have tried running it in an asynchronous way with an event delegate ( I think )  - but still timing out. Just plain weird.

Comment: OK - I figured it out .  I am obviously not handling serial port reads correctly.  the line string indata = sp.ReadLine().Replace("?","").Replace(" ","");  - if I remove it everything works fine.

Comment: @MartinThompson - Is it corrupting the Regex and giving you a bad weight?

Comment: No.  Serial port data comes in sporadically.  Sometime it will hit the serial port received event 50+ times - so I need to "gather" the data until it reaches a "\r\n" and then use that to move forward.   In nodejs - I used parsers which made things easy - it handled everything for me https://serialport.io/docs/api-parsers-overview

Answer (score 0):

Hans Passant as pointed out that most likely the cause isn't in the code structure at all, and most likely he's right. To test the hypothesis, descend into `trayWeighScan.doOrder` and change the async HttpClient async call into a sync call. If the problem goes away, my answer is good. If the problem remains, look elsewhere, say the network or the client machine's TCP stack or AV or somesuch.

I've not seen this exact thing before, but I've learned that launching async operations in a WinForms app doesn't do the expected when launched in the naive way. The following should work much better

```
    Task.Run(async () => {
        var jsonString = await trayWeighScan.doOrder(barcode, Decimal.Parse(weight);
        try
        {
            var jsonDoc = JsonDocument.Parse(jsonString);
            jsonData = JsonSerializer.Serialize(jsonDoc, new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true });
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            jsonData = jsonString;
        }
        this.Invoke(new Action(() => { scanData.Last().responseData = jsonData; }));
        this.Invoke(new Action(() => { responseTextBox.Text = jsonData; }));
        this.Invoke(new Action(() => { statusTextBox.Text = "Ready to Scan"; }));
        this.Invoke(new Action(() => { busy = false; }));
        });
```

Wrapping winforms-originating async in Task.Run seems to completely fix the problem.

A lot of stuff talks about `.ConfigureAwait()` being the solution; but it's overly complex. The simplest and best solution is to only spawn async/await from threadpool threads, which means starting an async/await chain from Task.Run.

Comment: THanks - I'm getting Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string>' to 'string'  - and I can't explicitly cast either..?

Comment: @MartinThompson: I made a change that should make it more library version tolerant

Comment: sorry that made no difference but thanks for your time.